# C# Character from Unicode

Tags: c#, unicode

I have a unicode character from the FontAwesome cheat sheet:

`#xf042;`

How do I put that character into c# ?

string s = "????";

I have tried entering it is as and using a .

Comment: `string s = "\uf042"`

Comment: @zerkms It's a private use area, so how it looks will depend on the font. But why does make the codepoint invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the hex input represents UTF8 encoded string you could have a function that will convert a HEX string:

```
public static string ConvertHexToString(string hex)
{
    int numberChars = hex.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[numberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberChars; i += 2)
    {
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    }
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
}
```

and then filter out the unnecessary characters from your input before feeding it to this function:

```
string input = "#xf042;";
string s = input.Replace("#x", string.Empty).Replace(";", string.Empty);
string result = ConvertHexToString(s);
```

Obviously you will need to adjust the correct encoding based on the input, because the hex simply represents a byte array and in order to decode this byte array back to a string you're gonna need to know the encoding.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a lighter version of what Darin posted to convert the hex value to a string containing the unicode position from the private area of the FontAwesome font, you can use this >>

```
private static string UnicodeToChar( string hex ) {
    int code=int.Parse( hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber );
    string unicodeString=char.ConvertFromUtf32( code );
    return unicodeString;
}
```

Just call it as follows >>

```
string s = UnicodeToChar( "f042" );
```

Alternatively, you can simply use the C# class with all the icons and loader pre-written here >>  [FontAwesome For WinForms CSharp](https://github.com/microvb/FontAwesome-For-WinForms-CSharp)